# Drupal how to use a sql case statement alike

Tags: drupal-8

I need to update all the nodes in the database based on a certain condition, and I need this update to be conditional. If a certain field is equal to a value, what the modified value will be X If it is otherwise, the value will be y, in a more accurate sense, I need something similar to the case statement in the sql.

```
Update [node]
Set    [field] = CASE WHEN [field] IN (value1, value2, ...) THEN X ELSE Y END
WHERE  [field] = value
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I do not know much about Drupal and I thought that there may be a function provided by the Drupal to modify all the nodes once instead of bringing all the nodes and looping on them one by one and update each separately, so is there such a function in the Drupal? What I have done now is use the ternary operator to choose between the two values ​​to set and use the set function on the node object.

Comment: Can you execute the SQL query directly? Or you want it to be executed from Drupal?

Comment: I want to implement this through Drupal as its database is unusual and it cannot be added or deleted from it through regular query statements. Regarding its database is unusual, for every field in the site built on the basis of Drupal there is a pair of tables and accordingly you must use the functions provided by Drupal to interact with its database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the ternary operator to choose between the two values ​​to set and use the set function on the node object